# Hardwired Networking Issue (fresh install)

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, internet

I've done a fresh install of Ubuntu on my desktop. The ethernet adapter (RTL-8100/8101L/8139) is recognized by the OS yet I can't connect to the internet. The Cat 5 connection to the router is good (tried it on another computer). Here are some outputs from my testing:

DHCPv4 request timed out.

ip-config -> failed (reason 'ip-config-unavailable')

'Wired connection 1' invalid.

Activation (eth0) failed for connection 'Wired connection 1'

device state change: failed -> disconnected (reason 'none')

deactivating device (reason 'none')

What can I do to get this box connected to the net? It's nice that the systems tells me that it is disconnecting and deactivating the connection but I'd like more info than 'none'.

Comment: This could help:

http://askubuntu.com/questions/596195/internet-does-not-work-over-wired-connection-after-removing-pppoe-configs/596338#596338

Comment: It couldn't be that easy. I don't have the option of 'Auto Ethernet'. I stick myself with the tough challenges. Thanks though.

Comment: Can you please post the output of `sudo lshw -C network`, `ifconfig eth0`, and the content of the network connection configuration file in `/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/`.

Answer (score 0):

My gut is telling me that it's either:

- A kernel module issue (e.g. the wrong kernel module is being loaded or the card was very different than an earlier revision, no model number was changed my the manufacturer, and the module matching that name doesn't support a newer chip that was swapped out in a later run. (seen that a bunch with cheap usb wifi cards))

  ***or***
- Network Manager conflicting with something (like configs in `/etc`.) Network Manager does a great job of 'just working' [ https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkManager ], but if you've added stuff to `/etc/network/interfaces` then something there may be tripping it up.

In either case you will probably have to do some reading and poke around your configs some. Since you said that it was a fresh install, it seems to be detecting something, the DHCP client sounds installed, and you've confirmed that the router is correctly giving out IP addresses, then I'm veering towards something having to do with the kernel module. Wired networking almost always works out of the gate with Ubuntu 14.04 when the kernel stuff is right.